# Is there an advantage of DOM manipulation using D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dom, dom-events

I have some Javascript code that draws a map using the HTML `<canvas>` element. I came up with using D3 alongside, but now I notice that I use it only for purposes of DOM manipulation, because the actual drawing is carried out by the functions of the canvas API. For example, to create a simple HTML slider, I could use:

```
let slider = d3.select('body').append('input')
    .attr('type', 'range')
    .attr('min', 0)
    .attr('max', 100);
```

The same could be achieved without D3 using:

```
let slider = document.createElement('INPUT');
    slider.setAttribute('type', 'range');
    slider.setAttribute('min', 0);
    slider.setAttribute('max', 100);

document.body.appendChild(slider);
```

I am considering to replace all the DOM manipulation by pure javascript in the whole document, but maybe there are some advantages of using D3 that I don't see now. Besides, if I want to attach an event handler to that slider, like `slider.oninput = updateFunction;` this seems to work only with pure JS, as I didn't find a way to pass the `e` parameter within the D3 way so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this might be a bit opinion based. If you are using D3 just for some DOM manipulation, you are probably better off just using regular JS. Unless you are using more of the `update enter append` flow of dynamic generation, there is probably little need. Its just another ~70kb of JS your users have to download. As with d3 event handlers and getting the event, [here](https://www.dashingd3js.com/lessons/d3-and-dom-events) is a handy guide. Basically d3 events get a data element and an index, with the traditional DOM event object in d3.event.

```js
d3.select('div').on('click', function(d, i) {
  // d is the elements data point if you have bound data
  const e = d3.event // d3 binds the event into d3.event
});
```